# I am optimizing a 5 bus system with 2 storage units in PyPSA and not able to visualize all outputs

Tags: optimization, jupyter-notebook, mathematical-optimization, modeling, pypsa

While optimizing 5 bus system. After doing lopf by GLPK solver, I am able to visualize the real power flow (P)in the lines with the command 'network.lines_t.p0' and the phase angle with the command 'network.buses_t.v_ang * 180 / np.pi' for each time step, but unable to see the voltage magnitude with the commannd "network.buses_t.v_mag_pu_set", and neither able to see the reactive power (Q). Please help me with a solution so that I can see all the results.

I made all the csv files for buses, loads, lines, generators, load_p_set, generator-pmax_pu. and did the lopf optimization. After this, I am not able to visualize my results. Specially the magnitudes of each bus voltages, and the reactive power flow in the lines.

Comment: Please add the code you have so far, and enough data to reproduce the problem.